# bees SDK is attempting to communicate with localhost

Tags: cloudbees

The cloudbees SDK 1.1 is attempting to connect to localhost:8080 when I run commands.

Any idea what I need to do to fix it?

Example

```
bees app:info -v
# CloudBees SDK version: 1.1
Enter application ID (ex: account/appname) : account/app
API call: http://localhost:8080/api?timestamp=1344846702&v=1.0&api_key=KEY&action=application.info&app_id=account%2Fapp&format=xml&sig_version=1&sig=SIGN
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request: Connection refused
Aug 13, 2012 6:31:42 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetry
INFO: Retrying request

ERROR: Connection refused
```

Thank you 
Jono

Answer (score 2):

Add `bees.api.url=https\://api.cloudbees.com/api` to `~/.bees/bees.config`

After backing up `~/.bees` and then running bees init and recreating my bees configuration directory  I noticed the extra entry in `bees.config`.

Comment: was this due to an older config? ie upgrade problem? good catch !